# Pass arguments in to a Type that is supplied to an Attribute

Tags: c#, validation, attributes

I have an attribute that I am using to decorate object properties with. The attribute identifies the properties as needing validation to be performed on them. I am essentially implementing the Strategy Pattern and building all of the validation (really only about 6 types) in to individual objects that I can use across multiple classes. What I want to do, is provide parameters to the validation classes, without having to create an attribute for each validation object variation.

My attribute looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ValidationRuleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ValidationRuleAttribute(Type validationRule, string customFailureMessage = "")
    {
        if (typeof(IValidationRule).IsAssignableFrom(validationRule))
        {
            this.ValidationRule = string.IsNullOrEmpty(customFailureMessage) 
                ? Activator.CreateInstance(validationRule, customFailureMessage) as IValidationRule
                : Activator.CreateInstance(validationRule) as IValidationRule;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format(
                    "ValidationRule attributes can only be used with IValidationRule implementations. The '{0}' Tyoe is not supported.",
                    validationRule.Name));
        }
    }

    public IValidationRule ValidationRule { get; private set; }
}
```

As an example, I have a simple StringIsNotNull validation object. I want to expand on it by allowing me to specify a minimum string length requirement. So the `StringIsNotEmptyValidation` would become `StringHasMinimumLengthValidation`

```
public class StringIsNotEmptyValidation : IValidationRule
{
    private readonly string customErrorMessage;

    public StringIsNotEmptyValidation()
    {
    }

    public StringIsNotEmptyValidation(string customErrorMessage)
    {
        this.customErrorMessage = customErrorMessage;
    }

    public string ResultMessage { get; private set; }

    public IValidationMessage Validate(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property, IValidatable sender)
    {
        string value = property.GetValue(sender).ToString();            

        // Validate
        bool isFailed = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
        if (isFailed)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.customErrorMessage))
            {
                DisplayNameAttribute displayName = property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>(true);

                string errorMessage = displayName == null
                    ? string.Format("You can not leave {0} empty.", property.Name)
                    : string.Format("You can not leave {0} empty.", displayName.DisplayName);

                this.ResultMessage = errorMessage;

                return new ValidationErrorMessage(errorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ResultMessage = this.customErrorMessage;
                return new ValidationErrorMessage(customErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        this.ResultMessage = string.Empty;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Within my model, I decorate my property with the attribute and validation object.

```
[RepositoryParameter(DbType.String)]
[ValidationRule(typeof(StringIsNotEmptyValidation))]
public string WorkDescription
{
    get
    {
        return this.workDescription ?? string.Empty;
    }

    set
    {
        this.SetPropertyByReference(ref this.workDescription, value);

        if (this.HasValidationMessageType<ValidationErrorMessage>(this.GetPropertyName(p => p.WorkDescription)))
        {
            this.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is write my attribute usage like this:

```
[ValidationRule(new StringIsNotEmptyValidation(minimumLength: 4))]
```

Since you can't instance objects in an attribute constructor, I'm forced to provide the attributes in my attribute constructor like this:

```
[ValidationRule(typeof(StringIsNotEmptyValidation), minLength: 4)]
```

I don't like this because if I have a `ObjectIsNotNull` or a `StringIsInRange` I will need to do two things:

1. Create a new attribute for each parameter variation (or a *lot* of overloads)
2. Set up the validation rule instances within the constructor, which will have varying property names.

The Validation object implements the following interface

```
public interface IValidationRule
{
    string ResultMessage { get; }

    IValidationMessage Validate(PropertyInfo property, IValidatable sender);
}
```

I don't want to bloat my interface with a large number of properties that might be used or might not be used depending on the Rule implementing it. It also makes it difficult to assign attribute params to the rule object.

So my question is how can I provide parameters to the `IValidationRule` concrete classes, without creating multiple attribute types to facilitate this? This is being used so that I an do cross-object validation. The PropertyInfo passed in to the validation rule is from a cache of PropertyInfo's. I need to keep the amount of reflection used down, otherwise I'd just use attributes for each *rule parameter* and use reflection on `sender` to figure out what ranges to use.

### Update

After discussing this with Corey, it does indeed appear that attributes are supported in Universal Apps and it is only the `DataAnnotations` namespace that is missing. In order to get access to the attributes, I had to add a using statement to System.Reflection in order to gain access to a series of extension methods that expose the `GetCustomAttribute` methods. They are now extension methods and not built in to the Type class.

So I suppose in the end, I can just create my validation logic within the attributes, instead of individual objects. I can't think of any downsides to going this route.

In order to access the attributes in a Universal App, you have to include `System.Reflection` as a using statement, then access via the `GetRuntimeProperties()` extension method.

```
var validationRule = this
    .GetType()
    .GetRuntimeProperties() // Can be GetRuntimeFields or GetRuntimeMethods as well.
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<IntegerInRangeAttribute>() != null);
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Data Annotations already in the BCL?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had looked at it. The reason why I was moving away from it (used it in the past) is due to wanting to use validation across platforms. For WPF I can use data annotations, but Universal Windows Apps don't support attributes. Since Data Annotations rely on a ValidationContext that parses the attribute data, I can't really use it. Instead, I am creating ValidationObjects that are self contained. On WPF, the attributes auto-wire. In Universal Apps, the attributes are left off and the objects build a collection of validation objects in their constructor and can still self-validate.

Comment: I want to apply the same validation across multiple platforms, so by using the Strategy Pattern, I can encapsulate the business validation in to independent, reusable, objects that I can use across platforms, or even have view models force per-property validation on models if needed (although I know _that_ part can be done with INDEI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few options here.

First, and often used, is to have a different attribute for each type of rule you want to process.  You are already building classes for each of your rules, so instead of having some encapsulating attribute that instantiates them all just make each rule an attribute:

```
[StringMinLengthRule(5)]
public string SomeString { get; set; }
```

Build the validation logic into your attributes - say with a base attribute that does the bulk of the work, calling a virtual method to do the actual validation.  Then you can just enumerate the rule attributes and call them from your validation method.

Next, you can have a number of different properties on your attribute that can be set during declaration to provide the properties for your various rules:

```
[Validation(RuleType.StringMinLength, MinLength = 5)]
public string SomeString { get; set; }
```

You could still have the rules be processed in the `ValidationAttribute` itself, or create `IValidationRule` instances at run-time to process the actual validations.  Unfortunately there's nothing to stop you from adding a `Validation` attribute that sets the wrong properties for the rule type, resulting in errors at run-time when you try to validate an instance.

Finally, something that works but probably shouldn't... and it's kinda ugly:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ValidationRuleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IValidationRule ValidationRule { get; private set; }
    public ValidationRuleAttribute(RuleType type, params object[] parms)
    {
        if (type == RuleType.NotNull)
        {
            if (parms.Length != 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("RuleType.NotNull requires 0 parameters", "parms");
            ValidationRule = new NotNullValidation();
        }
        if (type == RuleType.StringMinLength)
        {
            if (parms.Length != 1)
                throw new ArgumentException("RuleType.StringMinLength requires 1 parameter", "parms");
            if (!(parms[0] is int))
                throw new ArgumentException("RuleType.StringMinLength requires an integer", "parms");
            ValidationRule = new StringLengthValidation((int)parms[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest problem with it is that it won't complain until you try to instantiate a class at run-time that has a bad `Validation` attribute.  Your code can run quite happily up until the point where it tries to create an instance of that bad class, at which point all of the attributes will actually be constructed and those `ArgumentException`s start flying.

In fact only the first option doesn't suffer from run-time problems, because you can control the types of parameters being supplied by using the correct constructor formats.  You can still tell it to do silly things - like requiring that strings must have less than 0 length for instance - but that's up to you :P

Comment: I hadn't really thought about building an attribute to wrap my validation objects, allowing them to maintain their validation. Unfortunetaly I can't perform the actual validation in the attributes (which is why I'm not using Data Annotations) since Universal Apps don't support attributes. The goal was to allow WPF to decorate models with attributes pointing to validation rules, while Universal Apps still had access to the Rules, but had to invoke and setup manually via contructors. I'll look at wrapping the rules in attributes for the WPF implementation and see how that goes.

Comment: So you want to use attributes... but you don't want to use attributes?  Odd.  I've never tried to build a Universal App, but it seems weird that they'd take out attributes.  They're a core part of .NET after all.

Comment: Yeah, sadly they are not a part of the Universal App framework yet. The Data Annotations namespace and all of the GetCustomAttributes<T> methods were removed. So I'm stuck trying to support a platform that has attributes and one that does not. Which is why my logic is in non-attribute classes. Since the validation is abstracted away, it's not a big deal duplicating the models, one for WPf and one for Universal. I just don't want to reproduce all of the business logic, which is partly why I want to pass in range info to the Rule objects.

Comment: You can certainly use attributes with a PCL class library.  The code is slightly different, but it's there.  Can you link me to something that explains the limitation in Universal Apps?  Can't find anything here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find much documentation on Universal Apps specifically. I was told by the Patterns & Practice team that attributes are not included in Windows Universal Apps (but is supported in PCL), and this is the reason why their Prism for Universal Apps must use server side validation and not data annotations like Prism 5.0 does. I don't know why Microsoft didn't include it.

Comment: I believe the limitation is that the Windows Phone 8.1 framework does not support attributes, and that is the reason the universal apps do now support it. This is where a Patterns & Practices Prism codeplex coordinator told me this: https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/discussions/550430

Comment: While he mentions Data Annotation, there are not any additional assemblies that VS will let me add, and none of the attributes I try (DisplayNameAttribute etc) can be resolved by VS, so either VS is messed up or they don't exist in the Universal API :/ I can't find any documentation specifically for universal apps that explains the differences in API's, only documentation on each individual platform which isn't helpful. They both have their own different set of APIs and the Universal app converged them; without documentation stating what is now supported or not. Really frustrating.

Comment: From that discussion I don't get the impression that _all_ attribute support is missing - this would be a massive breaking change in the framework - but that there is no support for DataAnnotations on the client side.  That shouldn't stop you from creating and using your own attributes.  Just don't try to use the DataAnnotations attributes.

Comment: Please see my update to the OP. Since I can actually use Attributes now, I'll accept your answer. I'll see if I can figure out a way around creating 10 different InRangeOf attributes (one for each value type: int, double etc since generics are not supported on attributes) but if I have to do one per value type, then that's fine. It's still more straight forward than the original approach I was trying to take.

Comment: One attribute with different constructors for different range types perhaps?  Enumeration to specify to range method to use?  Numbers... convert them all to doubles to simplify the checks, etc.  Sounds like fun :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58083/discussion-between-johnathon-sullinger-and-corey).